Using WebApplicationFactory with Azure Functions in isolated mode
I am trying to use WebApplicationFactory for integration testing Azure Functions in .Net8 isolation mode but I am getting the following error when starting the test when reaching await host.RunAsync(); in program.cs
System.InvalidOperationException: The gRPC channel URI 'http://:' could not be parsed.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.GrpcServiceCollectionExtensions.GetFunctionsHostGrpcUri(IConfiguration configuration) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\GrpcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 97
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

However it runs fine when launched normal ways, but getting exception when hosted by WebApplicationFactory.
Maybe the problem is when I trigger a single test within Rider it will start the process as in-proc instead of isolated mode.
Any ideas how to configure WebApplicationFactory to use it in isolation mode?

Check this github issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/281, this feature yet to be added in isolated function
